# How to extract comments from SharePoint List?

Tags: excel, sharepoint

Is there any way to extract somehow comments from SharePoint list?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can use **REST API** to retrieve comments, and manage comments.

To get all comments from a modern page, make a Get request to:

```
#A page which has the id "xxx"
#/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Site Pages')/GetItemById("xxx")/Comments
        
#For example:
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Site Pages')/GetItemById(22)/Comments
```

[image]

[image]

**Here is a similar case for your reference:**

- [Sharepoint Online - comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/623610/sharepoint-online-comments.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to `Comments` API to get the comments:

`{webUrl}/_api/web/Lists(guid'{listId}')/GetItemById({itemId})/Comments`

Check out the article here:
https://www.eliostruyf.com/getting-likes-and-comments-from-modern-pages/